# Question on Riemann Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

The upper Riemann integral is defined as $\int_a^{-b}f(x)dx = \inf U(P,f)$, and the lower Riemann integral is defined as $\int_{-a}^{b}f(x)dx = \sup L(P,f)$, where $U$ and $L$ denote the upper and lower sums respectively, and the supremum and infimum are taken over all partitions $P$ of $[a,b]$.

I am able to visualize that $\sup L(P,f)$ and $\inf U(P,f)$ are basically the lower and upper Riemann sums as the number of 'rectangular blocks' tends to infinity, but I do not understand why the above two equalities hold. $\sup L(P,f)$ and $\inf U(P,f)$, I think, are essentially $\int_a^{b}f(x)dx$. But how could we say that this integral equals $\int_a^{-b}f(x)dx $ or $\int_{-a}^{b}f(x)dx$?

For example, let $f(x)=x^2, a = 1$ and $b=2$. In this case $\int_a^{b}f(x)dx$ = $\frac{7}{3}$ and $\int_{-a}^bf(x)dx = 3$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can say that $\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx$ is equal to both ${\underline\int}_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx$ and $\overline{\int}_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx$ because that's how we *define* $\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx$: it is equal to both those numbers when they're equal.

Besides,$$\underline{\int}_1^2x^2\,\mathrm dx=\frac73\ne3.$$It's up to you to tell us how is it that you got $3$.

Comment: It *is* 3. I've checked, and checked again.

Comment: You are defining $\underline{\int}_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx$ is the infimum of the set of all upper sums of $f$ with respect to all partitions of $[a,b]$, right?

Comment: No. I meant the supremum, I apologise for the typo.

Comment: However that doesn't change the fact that $\int_{-1}^2x^2dx=3$, and my question remains.

Comment: And who, besides you, defines it that way?

Comment: Well, that's the very definition stated by my professor. And here's a [link](https://people.math.sc.edu/sharpley/math554_s96/554_9/) that states the same.

Comment: Pleas see the standard definition [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125b/ch1.pdf), on page 3.

Comment: I'm sorry, but isn't this definition the same?

Comment: No. The definition from those notes is with the supremum of all lower sums and the infimum of all upper sums. At no point there is a reference to the supremum of all upper sums.

Comment: Oh, about that.. I had edited the question accordingly half an hour ago once you had pointed out that the definition I wrote at first was wrong(and it was). So I do not think that is a concern anymore. However please consider answering my actual question, perhaps explaining some intuition behind the definition. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133034/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-ambica-govind).